# PLSQL Dynamic SQL query select from a variable object

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Context:
We are in Oracle APEX, i'm writing a package to parse an XLSX file into an application, using the APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE function.

Due to the fact that the XLSX file could have any arbitry number of columns (from 1 to 300) i'm trying to code my function to be more efficient becouse now i'm calling the .PARSE function a lot.

What i've done:
I'm starting trying to know how many columns i have thar are not null (using apex_data_parser.get_columns) , then i call the parse function to save only the row (isthe first row) with the columns names into an object (in that case is the WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW object)
Then i have an WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW object with one row, that contain about 300 columns with the columns header text (some empty, some with text).

WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW schema is like that:
LINE_NUMBER, COL001, COL002.....COL300

I need to check if any of this header text exists in a table, so i thought to use dynamic sql to build a query like that:

```
V_ROW WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW;
v_data VARCHAR2(100);

v_sql := 'select V_ROW.COL001 into v_data from dual';
```

this kind of query works outside the execute immediate function only. It can't find the V_ROW.COL001 identifier if i call it using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

So for know i haven't find any better alternative than call the entire .PARSE procedure with dynamic sql to get one column at time:

```
 BEGIN
        <<iterazione>>
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Start Iterazione');
        FOR i in 1 .. v_column_count
            LOOP
                v_loop_col_number := 'COL0' || (17 + i - 1);
                v_loop_col_name := 'p.' || v_loop_col_number;

                v_sql := '
        select ' || v_loop_col_name || '
        from apex_application_temp_files f,
             table ( apex_data_parser.parse(
                     p_content => f.blob_content,
                     p_add_headers_row => ''Y'',
                     P_SKIP_ROWS => 1,
                     p_max_rows => 5,
                     p_store_profile_to_collection => ''FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION'',
                     p_file_name => f.filename) ) p
        where f.name = ''60214053546764711/reduced_DATALOAD_Import_Categorie_e_Attributi.xlsx''
          AND p.line_number = 2';
--                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Sql: ' || v_sql);
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql into test_res;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Attributo colonna: ' || v_loop_col_name || ' : ' || test_res);
            END LOOP;
```

It's a waste of time but i can't generate a dynamic sql code to select a single column from the object V_ROW i have (that contains the same data) so instead a call the entire parse procedur.
I really don't want to hardcode 300 column names... any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is definitely needed here, but your attempt needs a few tweaks. First, you need to pass in the record variable as an in-bind, and you need to pull your INTO clause out, and splice in the column number with string concatenation:

```
create type WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW is object (col001 varchar2(128),col002 varchar2(128),col003 varchar2(128));

DECLARE  
  V_ROW WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW := WWV_FLOW_T_PARSER_ROW('TEST1','TEST2','TEST3');
  v_data VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..3
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select :V_ROW.COL'||LPAD(i,3,'0')||' from dual' into v_data using IN V_ROW;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_data);
  END LOOP;
END;
```